# How do I turn the Bluetooth feature on my camera?

Tags: digital, bluetooth

How can I turn on the bluetooth feature on my D3200 Nikon camera? I seems to have lost it this morning.

Comment: The D3200 doesn't have Bluetooth.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I turn on the bluetooth feature on my D3200 Nikon camera?

You can't, since the D3200 does not have a Bluetooth transmitter or receiver.